# How to display a list of all commits with parents' information?

Tags: git

`git log` command can be used to see the entire list of commits of a repository.

`git cat-file commit commit_id` can be used to see more information about a particular commit, especially the commit parent(s).

Question: Is there a  `git log` option that also lets us see the parent(s) of each commit listed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
--parents
    Print also the parents of the commit (in the form "commit parent...").
    Also enables parent rewriting, see History Simplification above.
```